# efficient looping logistic regression in R

Tags: r, loops, runtime, regression

I'm trying to run multiple logistic regression analyses for each of ~400k predictor variables. I would like to capture the outputs of each run into a row/column of an output table.

My data organised in two parts. I have a 400000 x 189 double matrix (`mydatamatrix`) that contains the observations/data for each of my 400000 predictor variables measured in 189 individuals (`P1`). I also have a second 189 x 20 data frame (`mydataframe`) containing the outcome variable and another predictor variable (`O1` and `P2`) plus 18 other variables not used in this particular analysis.

My regression model is `O1~ P1+P2`, where `O1` is binary.

I got the following loop to work:

create output file for results

```
output<-data.frame(matrix(nrow=400000, ncol=4))
names(output)=c("Estimate", " Std. Error", " z value", " Pr(>|z|)")
```

run logistic regression loop for `i` predictors and store output in output file

```
for (i in c(1:400000)){
  result<-(glm(mydataframe$O1 ~ mydatamatrix[,i] + as.factor(mydataframe$P2),
               family=binomial))
  row.names(output)<-row.names(mydatamatrix)
  output[i,1]<-coef(summary(result))[2,1]
  output[i,2]<-coef(summary(result))[2,2]
  output[i,3]<-coef(summary(result))[2,3]
  output[i,4]<-coef(summary(result))[2,4]
}
```

However, the run time is huge (it took over an hour to output the first 20k tests). Is there a more efficient way to run this analysis?

Comment: My actual advice is likely to be a bit of a letdown: don't do this at all. Running 400k regressions on each variable is not likely to yield much useful information. At the very least, I would investigate some penalized regression methods for variable selection, like the lasso or LARS.

Answer (score 1):

It will be faster if you use `apply` instead of a `for` loop:

```
t(apply(mydatamatrix, 2,
        function(x)
          coef(summary(glm(mydataframe$O1 ~ x + as.factor(mydataframe$P2), 
                           family=binomial)))[2, 1:4]))
```

Comment: As long as they pre-allocated the results object, it is unlikely that `apply` will yield significant speed gains over a (well written) for loop.

Comment: @joran Agreed, but I think a speed gain is associated with using `coef` and `summary` only once instaed of four times.

Comment: True, I just suspect (but am willing to be proven otherwise) that given the total time scale here (hours, it seems) even that speed gain will be pretty small.

Comment: @sven Hohenstein, Thanks very much for your suggestion - Im only just getting familiar with R so any help is very much appreciated. Im running your script now although it is still taking some time, over an hour so far..

Comment: @joran, I suspect you are right- it is likely to take hours rather than minutes for the current analysis, hence my reason for seeking help on this forum. Could you clarify please clarify what you mean by pre-allocating the results object? Do you have any alternative suggestions for speeding up this analysis? I have several to do. Thanks!