# for loops for regression over multiple variables & outputting a subset

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, regression, output

I have tried to apply this QA: ["efficient looping logistic regression in R"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418148/efficient-looping-logistic-regression-in-r) to my own problem but I cannot quite make it work.  I haven't tried to use apply, but I was told by a few people that a for loop is the best here (if someone believes otherwise please feel free to explain!) I think this problem is pretty generalizeable and not too esoteric for the forum.

This is what I want to achieve: I have a dataset with 3 predictor variables (gender, age, race) and a dependent variable (a proportion) for 86 genetic positions for several people.  I want to run bivariate linear regressions for each position (so 86 linear regressions for 3 predictor variables).  Then I want to output the results in some easily legible format; my idea is a matrix with rows=gender, age, and race, and columns=the 86 positions.  There would be a p value for each row*column combination.  Then I could call the p values<0.1 (or whatever threshold I want) to easily see which predictors are significantly associated with proportion at each position.

This is the code I have so far.

```
BB <- seq.csv[,6:91]   #the data frame containing the 86 positions
AA <- seq.csv[,2:4]    #the data frame containing the 3 predictor variables

linreg <- matrix(NA,3,86)  #make a results vector and fill it with NA
    for (i in 1:86)     #loop over each position variable
    {
              for (j in 1:3)  #for each position variable, loop over each predictor
    {
              linreg[i,j] <- lm(BB[,i]~AA[,j])  #bivariate linear regression
}}
```

No matter how I change this (for example, simplifying it to loop over the positions for only one predictor), I still get an error that my matrices are not the same length (number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length).  In fact, length(linreg)=286 (3*86) and length(BB)=86 and length(AA)=3.  I know the latter two are dataframes, not matrices...but if I convert them to matrices I get an invalid type error (invalid type (list) for variable 'BB[, i]').  I do not know how to resolve this error because I just don't understand R well enough...I've consulted the books *Applied Statistical Genetics with R* and *Art of R Programming* to no avail, and I'm been Google searching all day.  And I haven't even gotten to the coding for outputting the results...

I'd appreciate any debugging tips or some suggestions on a better way to code this!  Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I think you need to talk to a statistician. I think you are in over your head and need to understand the issues better before attempting to do any coding yourself.

Comment: It'll make it easier to help if you post part of the structure of your data. Try pasting the output from `dput( head( BB[,6:10] ) )` and `dput( head( AA ) )`.

Comment: This sounds like some of the regrettable things I did in my PhD... Please talk to a stats advisor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really hard to give a definitive answer without *knowing* the structure of your data beforehand, but this *might* work. I'm assuming that your two data frames have the same number of rows (observations):

```
df <- cbind( AA[ , 2:4 ] , BB[ , 6:91 ] )
mods <- apply( as.data.frame( df[ , 4:89 ] ) , 2 , FUN = function(x){ lm( x ~ df[,1] + df[,2] + df[,3] } )

# The rows of this matrix will correspond to the intercept, gender, age, race, and the columns are the results for each of your 86 genetic postions
pvals <- sapply( mods , function(x){ summary(x)$coefficients[,4] )
```

As to whether or not that is the *right* thing to do I will trust to your judgement as a genetic epidemiologist!

Comment: Oh it's definitely not the right thing to do. This was part of a lab rotation - my responsibility was just to do the "bench work".  Now that I have the data my responsibility is really just to learn R.  I'm definitely aware of the problems of multiple testing, correlated data, and the other issues at hand.  But this isn't for my dissertation - once I learn what I need to in R, the data will disappear without a trace!

Comment: @user2100907 If the above wasn't what you were looking for please leave a comment so I can update the solution with what you are looking to do. :-) Cheers

Comment: Many thanks - this code does what I wanted to achieve with just a minor change (including an end bracket "}" to the pvals vector code before the final ")"