# Looping over combinations of regression model terms

Tags: r, apply, lm

I'm running a regression in the form

```
reg=lm(y ~ x1+x2+x3+z1,data=mydata)
```

In the place of the last term, `z1`, I want to loop through a set of different variables, `z1` through `z10`, running a regression for each with it as the last term. E.g. in second run I want to use

```
reg=lm(y ~ x1+x2+x3+z2,data=mydata)
```

in 3rd run:

```
reg=lm(y ~ x1+x2+x3+z3,data=mydata)
```

How can I automate this by looping through the list of z-variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linear Regression loop for each independent variable individually against dependent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036007/linear-regression-loop-for-each-independent-variable-individually-against-depend)

Comment: @SamFirke The OP will probably also need assistance in learning how to construct each formula (since their formula is a little more involved) using `paste` or something, and that information isn't at the question you linked to.

Comment: Yes, this is doable in R.  One approach is to use an apply function like `lapply` which will take your vector of 10 variables and return a list of 10 `lm` objects with just that variable changing.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418148/efficient-looping-logistic-regression-in-r and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304514/for-loops-for-regression-over-multiple-variables-outputting-a-subset?rq=1.  An apply function is more "R-ish" than a for-loop.

Comment: One more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17026386/210673

Comment: Thanks everybody for the quick response! Thanks again!

Comment: Also, you may like the `broom` package if you then want to get the coefficients out of the list of models and into a new data.frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this dummy data:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(y = rpois(100,5),
x1 = runif(100),
x2 = runif(100),
x3 = runif(100),
z1 = runif(100),
z2 = runif(100)
)
```

You could get your list of two `lm` objects this way:

```
 lapply(dat1[5:6], function(x) lm(dat1$y ~ dat1$x1 + dat1$x2 + dat1$x3 + x))
```

Which iterates through those two columns and substitutes them as arguments into the `lm` call.

As Alex notes below, it's preferable to pass the names through the formula, rather than the actual data columns as I have done here.

Comment: Not a fan of the use of the global `dat1` inside of `lapply` like that. I would probably use `as.formula(paste("y ~ ...", x, sep = "+"))` with the `data` argument to `lm` populated with another parameter in `function`.

Comment: @AlexA.: Thanks Alex for your comment. I'll try to incorporate it while udating the code.

Answer (score 6):

While what Sam has provided works and is a good solution, I would personally prefer to go about it slightly differently. His answer has already been accepted, so I'm just posting this for the sake of completeness.

```
dat1 <- data.frame(y = rpois(100, 5),
                   x1 = runif(100),
                   x2 = runif(100),
                   x3 = runif(100),
                   z1 = runif(100),
                   z2 = runif(100))

lapply(colnames(dat1)[5:6],
       function(x, d) lm(as.formula(paste("y ~ x1 + x2 + x3", x, sep = " + ")), data = d),
       d = dat1)
```

Rather than looping over the actual columns of the data frame, this loops only over the string of names. This provides some speed improvements as fewer things are copied between iterations.

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark({ lapply(<what I wrote above>) })
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr
# {lapply(colnames(dat1)[5:6], function(x, d) lm(as.formula(paste("y ~ x1 + x2 + x3", x, sep = "+")), data = d), d = dat1)}
#       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  4.014237 4.148117 4.323387 4.220189 4.281995 5.898811   100

microbenchmark({ lapply(<other answer>) })
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr
# {lapply(dat1[, 5:6], function(x) lm(dat1$y ~ dat1$x1 + dat1$x2 + dat1$x3 + x))}
#       min       lq     mean   median       uq    max neval
#  4.391494 4.505056 5.186972 4.598301 4.698818 51.573   100
```

The difference is fairly small for this toy example, but as the number of observations and predictors increases, the difference will likely become more pronounced.

Comment: +1, I agree that looping over the names is preferable.  You could shorten this to `lapply(names(dat1)[5:6], function(x) lm(as.formula(paste0("y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + ", x)), data = dat1))`.  What is the benefit of `data = d), d = dat1)`?

Comment: @SamFirke: As I understand it, the benefit of passing `dat1` as a parameter is to avoid using globals within the function.

Comment: Interesting answer! But will your solution apply to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58756403/combinations-of-variables-that-produce-the-smallest-quantities-in-an-r-function) as well?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what your final goal is, it can be *much* faster to fit a base model, update it with `add1`, and extract the F-test/AIC you want:

```
> basemodel <- lm(y~x1+x2+x3, dat1)
> 
> add1(object=basemodel, grep("z\\d", names(dat1), value=TRUE), test="F")
Single term additions

Model:
y ~ x1 + x2 + x3
       Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC F value Pr(>F)
<none>              477.34 164.31               
z1      1    0.0768 477.26 166.29  0.0153 0.9019
z2      1    5.1937 472.15 165.21  1.0450 0.3093
```

See also `?update` for refitting the model.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach using packages from the [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) / [tidyr](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/) family.  It restructures the data to a long form, then uses `group_by()` from the dplyr package instead of `lapply()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr) # for use_series ()
dat1 %>%
  gather(varname, z, z1:z2) %>% # convert data to long form
  group_by(varname) %>%
  do(model = lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + z, data = .)) %>%
  use_series(model)
```

This converts the data to a long format using `gather`, where the z-values occupy the same column. `use_series()` from the [magrittr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/magrittr.pdf) package return the list of `lm` objects instead of a `data.frame`.  If you load the [broom](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html) package, you can extract the model coefficients in this pipeline of code:

```
library(broom)
dat1 %>%
  gather(varname, z, z1:z2) %>%
  group_by(varname) %>%
  do(model = lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + z, data = .)) %>%
  glance(model) # or tidy(model)

Source: local data frame [2 x 12]
Groups: varname

  varname  r.squared adj.r.squared    sigma statistic   p.value df    logLik      AIC      BIC deviance df.residual
1      z1 0.06606736    0.02674388 2.075924  1.680099 0.1609905  5 -212.3698 436.7396 452.3707 409.3987          95
2      z2 0.06518852    0.02582804 2.076900  1.656192 0.1666479  5 -212.4168 436.8337 452.4647 409.7840          95
```

**Data:**

```
dat1 <- data.frame(y = rpois(100, 5), x1 = runif(100),
                   x2 = runif(100), x3 = runif(100),
                   z1 = runif(100), z2 = runif(100))
```

Comment: Thanks Sam for putting extra effort by adding another answer.