# Combinations of variables that produce the smallest quantities in an R function

Tags: r, function, loops, regression, combinations

I'm interested in finding out which combination of variables (`binge` `followup` `sreport` `age`) in my model below produce smallest `I2` statistic in rank order (smallest to largest). The `I2` from each model is obtained like so:

`I2 <- function(x)as.double(x$mod_info$I.2)`.

Is there a way to automate this in R by looping over formulas?

**Ex:** First fitting `effectsize ~ binge`, then `effectsize ~ binge + followup` then ...

***Note:*** suppose I have the names of all variables stored like so: `var.names = c("binge", "followup", "sreport", "age")`.

```
library(robumeta)

fit <- robu(effectsize ~ binge + followup + sreport + age, data = get(data(hierdat)), 
            study = studyid, var = var)

# Get the `I2` for the above model:

I2(fit) # gives 63.993

# Note: I think `lapply(seq_along(var.names), function(i)combn(var.names, i))` can 
                        # give us each combination that should be used in the formula.
```

Comment: Loop through what? All possible formulas? Perhaps show us a few non-loop, manual lines to understand your process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create all combinations of your explanatory variables as you suggest, with a small change (to unlist non-recursively), then convert to formulas:

```
combos <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(var.names), 
                        function(i) combn(var.names, i, simplify = FALSE)),
                 recursive = FALSE)

formulae <- lapply(combos, 
                   function(x) paste('effectsize ~', paste(x, collapse = '+')))
```

Then apply each formula to your data:

```
fit <- lapply(formulae, function(f) 
                         robu(as.formula(f), data = get(data(hierdat))))
```

You can then obtain your I2 on each member of the fit, and then a which.min() will give you the one with the smallest I2.