# R: extract regression results using two or more for loops

Tags: r, for-loop

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418148/efficient-looping-logistic-regression-in-r), I created the following matrix and `for` loops to loop through all regression combinations in my df:

```
all_lm <-data.frame(matrix(nrow=180, ncol=9))
names(all_lm)=c("col1", "col2", "Estimate", " Std. Error", " z value", " pValue", "2.5%", "97.5%", "r^2")
```

and to save the results, this:

```
for (i in c("A","B","C"))
for (j in c(1:10))
for (k in c("D","E"))
for (l in c("F", "G", "H")){
  form <- formula(paste0(i,"_PC_AB_",k, " ~ ", l))
  result<-lm(form, data = schools, subset=Decile==j)
  all_lm[i,1]<-i
  all_lm[i,2]<-j
  all_lm[i,3]<-round(coef(summary(result))[2,1],3)
  all_lm[i,4]<-round(coef(summary(result))[2,2],3)
  all_lm[i,5]<-round(coef(summary(result))[2,3],3)
  all_lm[i,6]<-round(coef(summary(result))[2,4],3)
  all_lm[i,7]<-round(confint(result)[2,1],2)
  all_lm[i,8]<-round(confint(result)[2,2],2)
  all_lm[i,9]<-round(summary(result)$r.squared, 3)
}
```

This loop configuration works when I use it to export plots in `Cairo`, but I realise that the `all_lm[i,n]` is an incorrect approach. I do not know enough about R to solve this. I've tried various combinations such as `all_lm[i,j,k,n]`. I have also tried { after each `for` but this did not work. How can i loop through the 180 regressions and store the results in my matrix?

Comment: Why only one set of braces for four control structures?

Comment: As I stated in my post, this exact same `for` loop configuration worked when used for the package `Cairo`. And as I also stated above, I tried { braces after all four control structures (with four at the end) but this did not work either. The problem is in `all_lm[i,1]', again, as stated above.

Comment: Brackets work for subsetting rows and columns. It's always `[row, column]`. Your `i` variable takes on values "A", then "B", then "C", then "D". So, when you run `all_lm[i, 1] <- i`, this is equivalent to `all_lm["A", 1] <- "A"` which won't work unless you have a row named `"A"`. Doesn't look like you have any row names, so this won't work.

Comment: Furthermore, this i-dependent line `all_lm[i, 1] <- i` is being run *many* more times than necessary. You're running it every time `i` or `j` or `k` or `l` increments. It should be inside your `i` loop, but outside the other loops. Same with the lines that only depend on `j`. Your subsequent `round(coef(summary(...)))` lines will have values that depend on `k` and `l` because your formula changes based on `k` and `l`, but the place you're storing them depends only on `i`, so you'll just end up overwriting the values with the newer values.

Comment: @LeroyTyrone braces don't have anything to do with this error, I was just saying consistent use of them, along with proper indentation will make your code a lot more readable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time in R, if you're being drawn to using a `for` loop (let alone nested for loops), you're probably on the wrong track.

The general approach to solving your problem is to use the `expand.grid` function to create all combinations of the inputs, then use `mapply` to repeatedly regress on each combination of inputs and return a list of results, then use `do.call` to combine the list of results into a data frame.

Your code should look something like this:

```
i <- c('A','B','C')
j <- 1:10
k <- c('D','E')
l <- c('F','G','H')

params <- expand.grid(i, j, k, l, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You now have a data frame of all combinations of inputs.

```
> head(params)
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1    A    1    D    F
2    B    1    D    F
3    C    1    D    F
4    A    2    D    F
5    B    2    D    F
6    C    2    D    F
> tail(params)
    Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
175    A    9    E    H
176    B    9    E    H
177    C    9    E    H
178    A   10    E    H
179    B   10    E    H
180    C   10    E    H
```

Now set up a function that `mapply` will use for each row of the params data frame.

```
# 
one_lm <- function(i, j, k, l) {  

  form <- formula(paste0(i,"_PC_AB_",k, " ~ ", l))
  result <- lm(form, data = schools, subset=Decile==j)

    list(
      col1 = i,
      col2 = j,
      estimate = round(coef(summary(result))[2,1],3),
      std_err  = round(coef(summary(result))[2,2],3),
      z_value  = round(coef(summary(result))[2,3],3),
      p_value  = round(coef(summary(result))[2,4],3),
      pct_2.5  = round(confint(result)[2,1],2),
      pct_97.5 = round(confint(result)[2,2],2),
      r_square = round(summary(result)$r.squared, 3)

    )
}
```

Now use `mapply` to process each combination one at a time, and return a list of estimates, std_err, etc for each row.

```
result_list <- mapply(one_lm, params[,1], params[,2], params[,3], params[,4], SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

You can then combine all those lists into a data frame using the the `do.call` and `rbind` functions together.

```
results <- do.call(rbind, result_list)
```